# Множество подключений к одной веб странице с разными прокси

Tags: c#, proxy, webbrowser

как лучше всего реализовать следующее: В текст боксе1 указан URL, в текст боксе 2 указаны прокси, каждая с новой строки. Необходимо по нажатию на кнопку открыть несколько экземпляров веб браузера, чтобы каждый из них зашёл и оставался на сайте по URL, используя прокси, естественно у каждого экземпляра браузера должна быть своя прокся. Также желательно, чтобы эти веб браузеры работали в скрытом режиме и не были видны пользователю. Собственно, как это лучше реализовать? Стандартный Web-Browser такое умеет или нужно искать сторонний браузер и как-то его подключать? Подскажите, куда вообще смотреть, что искать

Comment: Автор явно занимается вредоносным ПО

Comment: Скрыть веб-баузер = вредоносное ПО? Как это вообще связано? Я заметил, что тот же любой парсер работает в скрытом режиме, либо, как мне ответили ниже просто по запросам без веб браузера

Answer (score 0):

Стандартный веб-браузер это IE. Он довольно криво работает со скриптами. Если нужна реализация конкретно через браузер, то надо смотреть в сторону headless браузеров, например, CEF(Chromium Embeded Framework) - у него есть .NET обертка, еще есть что-то там от Firefox. 
Однако работать через браузеры - довольно кривой подход, который требует много оперативной памяти, а его быстродействие оставляет желать лучшего. 
Если сайт не сложный, то лучше разобраться с запросами и общаться с сайтом на уровне HTTP.

Comment: Смотрите, вот мне нужно, чтобы сайт засчитывал, что на нем сейчас находится человек, самый просто пример это количество зрителей на стриме, если просто отправить запрос, то сайт же не будет считать, что зритель находится на стриме, верно? Как с помощью запросов удерживать условного "юзера" на сайте? Подразумеваю, что каждая прокся = 1 "юзер"

Comment: А как это происходит в обычном браузере? Браузер ведь тоже не волшебное устройство. Он по сути HTTP-клиент и точно так же кидает запросы. 
Как именно реализована система "Онлайн" зависит от сайта. Может быть какой-нибудь скрипт диктует браузеру раз в 5 секунд кидать запрос или просто устанавливается соединение без ответа(LongPolling) или там WebSocket.